# Direct proof - DROP-OUT (A) is a regular language

Tags: solution-verification, automata, automated-theorem-proving

Proposition: Let A be a regular language over $\Sigma$. Define DROP-OUT(A) to be the language containing all strings that can be obtained by removing one symbol from a string in A. Thus,
DROP-OUT(A) $= \{xz \mid xyz \in A,\  x,\ z \in Σ^{\ast}, y \in \Sigma\}$. Show that the class
of regular languages is closed under the DROP-OUT operation.

Proof: Suppose $A$ is a regular language and $A = \{xyz \mid x,z ∈ Σ^{\ast}, y \in \Sigma\}$.  Let xyz be an arbitrary word belonging to the language A and let X, Y and Z be regular languages ​​such that $X = \Sigma^{\ast}$, $Z = \Sigma^{\ast}$ and $Y = \Sigma$.
Then, we have $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ and $z ∈ Z$. Thus, we have $xyz \in XYZ$, and since $xyz \in A$, it follows that $A \subseteq XYZ$. Now, we can build a new language by concatenating X and Z as follows, $W = XZ$. So, we built  a language W starting from A, removing the language Y and concatenating as X and Z languages. As $W = XZ, xz \in W$ and $xz \in$ DROP-OUT(A) we can conclude that DROP-OUT(A) $\in W = XY$. Recall that regular languages are closed under concatenation. Therefore, as DROP-OUT(A) is formed by concatenation of two regular languages ​​we have that DROP-OUT(A) is a regular language. So if A is a regular language then DROP-OUT(A) is also regular.

Does my arguments suffices to prove that DROP-OUT(A) is a regular language?

Should I prior prove that X, Y and Z are regular languages too?

What can I do to improve it?

Comment: Do you know of epsilon-transitions? What if you take your language, construct its dfa, put epsilon transitions and conclude that dropout is the language accepted by that. Cause this seems not very unambiguous.

Comment: In such case I will have to give a correctness proof don't ? If so I wanted to avoid to give a correctness proof in the case of give an automaton as part of the proof.

Comment: See [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/130424).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some major problems with your argument. First, $XYZ$ contains every word over $\Sigma$ that contains a $y$. It is entirely possible that $A$ contains words that do not contain $y$, in which case $A$ is **not** a subset of $XYZ$: from the fact that $xyz$ in $A$ you cannot conclude that $A\subseteq XYZ$. Your $W$ is simply $\Sigma^*$; it’s a subset of $\operatorname{DROP-OUT}(A)$ if and only if $\operatorname{DROP-OUT}(A)=\Sigma^*$. This certainly need not be the case.

Here’s an example that illustrates both problems. Let $\Sigma=\{x,y\}$; the language $A=\{x,xyx\}$ over $\Sigma$ is certainly regular, and it contains the word $xyx$, which is in your $XYZ$ with $X=Z=\Sigma^*$ and $Y=\{y\}$. However, $x\in A\setminus XYZ$, because $x\notin XYZ$. And $\operatorname{DROP-OUT}(A)=\{x\}$, which is very far from being $\Sigma^*$.

I do not at the moment see any way to repair this argument; I think that you need a fresh start. Like **Phicar**, I’d be inclined to argue via automata, though I might do it without $\epsilon$-transitions.

Comment: Is there a way that I can show it as a concatenation of three regular languages? I am afraid that besides give an automaton the need to prove the correctness.

Comment: @Felipe: I really don’t see how.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for reply.

Comment: @Felipe: You’re welcome. If I think of anything along the lines that you want, I’ll add it, but I’m not hopeful.

Comment: @Felipe: In the first sentence of the second paragraph of that proof he should say ‘Now, $q_{\color{red}{k}}\in\delta'(q_{k-1},\epsilon)$. His notation $'r_i$ in the third sentence is a bit confusing, but I finally realized what he means. That $r_i$ is in $Q'$, so $r_i=q'$ for some $q\in Q$; by $'r_i$ he means the corresponding state $q\in Q$. In other words, if $r\in Q'$, $'r$ is the corresponding statei in $Q$, so that automatically $r=('r)'$: first we remove the prime, and then we put it back. In the next sentence the string $r_0\ldots r_{k-1}'r_k\ldots'd_n$ has the primes misplaced; ...

Comment: ... the $d$ should be $r$, and the string should be $r_0\ldots r_{k-1}{'r_k}\ldots{'r_n}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering.
When he writes $r_{i+1} \in \delta′(r_{i}, s_{i}) = \{\delta(r_{i},s_{i})\}$, it should be
$r_{i+1} \in \delta′(r_{i}, s_{i}) = \{\delta(r_{i},s_{i+1})\}$?

Comment: @Felipe: You’re right; I missed that error.

Comment: No problem. I tried to rewrite his proof with a different notation, but I am not that sure what I did is correct. However, that proof kinda helped me to think about a way to solve a related problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113972/discussion-between-felipe-and-brian-m-scott).